# Providing state for a oauth.io call with server-side auth (using iOS SDK)

Tags: ios, oauth

I'm trying to use oauth.io with Twitter or Facebook, with server-side auth, from an iOS app. I can connect to the service using `[_oauthio showWithProvider:providerName];`, and the connection returns without error. However, what I get is

`oauthtest://localhost#oauthio={"status":"error","message":"You must provide a state when server-side auth","provider":"twitter"}`

In other words, it requires a `state` parameter. But there is no obvious way to add this to the call anywhere? Does anyone know how to add this?

UPDATE: I dug down into the oath.io SDK, and spliced a `&state=abc` into the URL construction inside the `showProviderWith:` method, but that still gives the same result: connection returns successfully, but content indicates error as above.

Using a different provider, Facebook, I get exactly the same result (though, of course, with `"provider":"Facebook"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, found the answer by looking at the oauth.io *Android SDK*: There is a facility to add a state parameter, but it is as a **URL-encoded JSON object**. So the correct way to pass it in the iOS query string is to have a query parameter `opts` which has as its value `{"state":"STATE_HASH_HERE"}`.

The full query string with a state value would thus look like this:

`https://oauth.io/auth/twitter?k=<PUBLIC_KEY>
&opts=%7B%22state%22%3A%22<STATE_VALUE>%22%7D
&redirect_uri=OAuthTest://localhost`

(where %7B = {, %22 = ", %3A = :, and %7D = } for the percent encoding of the JSON object.)

The crucial element is the wrapping up inside the `opt` parameter. None of that is actually included in the oauth.io iOS SDK.

**UPDATE**: my pull-request has now been merged, and there is a new method which can be used to pass options: `[_oauthio showWithProvider:@"twitter" options:@{@"state": <STATE_VALUE>}];`.
`

Comment: I have now submitted a pull request to oauth.io that includes the ability to add options to the server call. OAuth.io works really nicely now, and makes integration painless.